# How can I work with dynamic table names together with sp_executesql in a while loop?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, while-loop

I have a number of fixed table names in a database. I need to collect the same type of data from all these tables and I need the select-statement to be easy to adjust and maintain for more than one person. The last bit we usually solve by putting these code parts "outside" the code that runs them.

To do all this I first tried to do a loop over a list with the table names. But as far as I figured out, TSQL (or SQL) don't have that functionality. Therefore I declared a counter and uses that counter to define my table names with an if-statement. Since I also need to print out the tablenames for a log, I don't succed to use the exec-statement. So, I'm trying to solve this by using sp_executesql together with dynamic table names in a while loop. The setup is (simpliefied) as follows:

```
declare @r nvarchar(max), @p nvarchar(150), @t nvarchar(40), @i int, @t1 varchar(8), @t2 varchar(8), @t3 varchar(8)

set @r = N'print @tab select * from ' + @t + '
set @p = N'@tab nvarchar(40)'
set @i = 1
set @t1 = 'A'
set @t2 = 'B'
set @t3 = 'C'

while @i < 4
begin

if @i = 1 set @t = @t1
else if @i = 2 set @t = @t2
else if @i = 3 set @t = @t3

set @t = concat('tmp_',@t)

exec sp_executesql @r, @p, @tab = @t

set @i = @i + 1
end
```

This gives a message that say *Commands completed successfully.* Nothing more. If I change the *set @r* statement to as shown below, it all works fine:

```
set @r = N'print @tab'
```

I can get it to work with *EXEC* command, but that means that I have to place the set @r statement in the loop, which makes it less smooth for me, since I want to reuse the *@r-code* later, in a different loop again.

Is there a way to do this in TSQL?

(Due to strict secretes I'm unable to copy and paste the actual code I'm running here. The script works as it looks without the select-statement or with an exec-statement but without the print-statement. Any syntax misspelling that might appear is from when I manually rewrote the generalised code here.)

Comment: `@t` has no value (well it's `NULL`), so `N'print @tab select * from ' + @t + '...'` has the value `NULL` and thus nothing is run. Also syntax like `N'...' + @t + N'...` is **extremely** dangerous. *Always* use `QUOTENAME` to inject your dynamic objects. Finally, your statements such as `if @i = 1 set @t = 'A'` are inside the dynamic statement, but the single quotes (`'`) aren't escaped, so the above will actually cause a syntax error.

Comment: Also you have an extra quote on line 2, and a `while/if` loop is a bit of a code smell anyway. What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Sorry for the inconvenience my "short cut" created with the variable-names. I've adjusted the code so it look more like the actual code in the it- and set-statement in the while-loop. I also added a more clearly and detailed explanation of what I'm trying to do and why I'm trying to do it.